# Non uniform unwrap on beveled mesh

Tags: uv

I have a beveled model, and need to use cube unwrap, the issue is with subsurface modifier which, when is set to catmull clark, smoothes the beveled part in a unwanted way.

here is a picture of the issue:
[image]

Same with options smooth to to 'None':
[image]

And the desired result with the subdivision set to simple:
[image]

Why is the smooth uv option not being effective ? How can I solve that ?

Comment: Is the unwrap correct? Please pack your image and share your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use some support edges. Do you have some crease value set up >0?

Comment: No, no crease set. What do you mean by support edges ? One more cut ?

Comment: Ok got it, unwrap is behaving as expected with support edges

Comment: @Yvain If the answer solved your problem, kindly accept it.